# After save data. then pop viewController

Tags: ios, swift

I want a idea that after save data to database complete, then pop current view controller. 
how can I do it. hope you can help me. Thanks

Update ---------------
This is my code now.

```
   /**
     The VC is puch in. When the VC will disappear, include pop with click back BarButtonItem, or pop by side swipeGestureRecognizer. I upload the data to server.
     But it not perfect
    */
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        NetworkSyncManager.syncyData { [unowned self](resutl) in
            self.endRefreshing()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use this code in your VC to pop it. self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil). or please take a look at unwind segue. BTW, you can add some code here to address your question clearly

Comment: Thank for you reply. and I updated the question with my code.

Answer (score 0):

its very simple to acheive this using a single LOC, firstly store your data to db then do the following.

- if your VC was pushed and now you want to pop use following code

  self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
- if your VC was presented and now you want to dismiss use following code

  self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: Thank you . I got your meaning

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback like blocks or delegate to achieve